# Django exclude filed__in not filtering data

Tags: django

So i have this query

```
data_list = ModelOffice.objects.values_list('office_name',flat=True)
data = ModelPerson.objects.filter().exclude(flag=1,office_name__in=data_list)
```

i want to pick a person that not have office in ModelOffice, but it still pick it

Comment: Why can't you just use `office_name__not_in` instead?

Comment: try this `data_list = list(ModelOffice.objects.values_list('office_name',flat=True))`